# Can't put stroke width or fill on a path

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stroke, fill

I'm a newbie.
I traced a photo with live trace, it looked good. Then I expanded it, and I can't get these paths to fill or take a stroke width, whether its grouped or not.
I drew a rectangle and it looks good and shows a fill and stroke width.

[image]

Comment: the traced result show only fills ... tracing could not predict the outline value of your artwork.

Comment: You might get a good answer if you edit your question to show a picture example.

Comment: If you can't fill and stroke *that* path you need to determine what's special about it. Is it a compound path? A mask?

Comment: I would say thsi is impossible to answer because we have no clue what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your layers panel in your screenshot it looks like you might have accidentally converted your shape to guides. Your layer icon is showing a blue box and typically it will preview the whole shape contained in that layer which would include your custom shape.

[image]

Guides are ignored in an icon preview. So I highly believe your shape is no longer an official "shape".

To undo this select your guide. If you can't View > Guides > *Uncheck* Lock Guides
Then Select the gude and **View > Guides > Release Guide**

Comment: that doesnt seem to be the issue because i had already deleted the extras when they showed up after editing with handles and adding nodes. i transformed the edited version away and deleted two duplicates, but the problem is still there. hmmm Thanks for the response though!

Comment: i found i had a rectangle around it i thought was just the artboard but it had anchors on it, i deleted them, but still no stroke weight showing, although i told it 9pt.

Comment: See my edited answer, your shape has been converted to a guide accidentally.